# Greater Coverage on a simple trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'd like to know how to get more coverage on a fairly simple trigger, both for practical deployment but also for understanding coverage better.
My trigger copies many fields into a large text field in another object for processing in another system:

```
trigger insertCustomObjectProspect on Opportunity (after update) {
 Set<Id> Ids= new Set<Id>();
    for (Opportunity OppToMessage : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(OppToMessage.Approval_Status__c =='New Accounts Final Approval' ){
        Ids.add(OppToMessage.Id);   
        }  

    }
    List<Opportunity> memberList = new List<Opportunity>([Select

    Id,
    //many many other fields

     From Opportunity e where Id in :Ids]);  


       for(Opportunity temp : memberList )
    {
    Custom_Object__c CustomObject = new Custom_Object__c();
        CustomObject.Body__c = 

     'OpportunityID,' + temp.id + '||~||' +   
    'Description,'+temp.Description + '||~||'+ 
    'StageName,'+temp.StageName + '||~||'+
    'Type,'+temp.Type + ';'
    //all those other fields

;

     insert CustomObject;
     }
 }
```

My test class :

```
@isTest
private class insertCustomObjectProspectTest {
    @isTest static void test1() {

 Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];


    Account testA = new Account(name='testing Account', A_client_id__c='9999999999') ;
    insert testA;


Opportunity THEOPP = new Opportunity (Account=testa, stageName = 'Prospecting', name='OppName', closeDate = system.today(), owner=cdz);
insert THEOPP;



    THEOPP.Approval_Status__c = 'New Accounts Final Approval';


     List <Custom_Object__c> CreatedCustomObjects = New List <Custom_Object__c> ([select id, body__c, opportunity__c from Custom_Object__c where Opportunity__c =:theopp.id limit 1]);

    for (Custom_Object__c OOO: CreatedCustomObjects){
        system.assert (ooo.Opportunity__c == THEOPP.id);
    }

     }
}
```

Lines from the trigger that are not covered:

```
 Ids.add(OppToMessage.Id);
```

and

```
 {


    CUstom_Object__c AIMSMEssage = new CUstom_Object__c();
       CustomObject.Body__c =
```

and

```
insert CustomObject;
```

Do I need to system assert on these actions? That the body matches? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating your opportunity after changing the Stage.

Add that update call shown in line 2 below into your code and you should be good to go

```
THEOPP.Approval_Status__c = 'New Accounts Final Approval';
update THEOPP;
List <Custom_Object__c> CreatedCustomObjects = New List <Custom_Object__c> ([select id, body__c, opportunity__c from Custom_Object__c where Opportunity__c =:theopp.id limit 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it went to 100%. I thought my system assert passing meant that it had updated and made, but it looks like a null was also able to pass it.

Comment: I don't think it ever hit your assert statement as you are looping through an empty list.  Since you never had the update statement, a custom object was never created, so your for loop is looping through an empty list, so the assert statement is never made.  You can test that by adding a debug statement inside the for loop.

Comment: right, so my empty list didn't do nuttin

Comment: lol....yes, basically.  Glad its working now though.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this is to have two separate methods in my test class so that I can test the scenarios rather than just focusing on coverage. It seems to me that you might need to actually do an update after the line

```
THEOPP.Approval_Status__c = 'New Accounts Final Approval';
```

in your test class, this will 'commit' the change to the DB and then run the trigger, so it should enter the IF block which is not currently being entered as part of the test class execution.

Hence, why I would separate into two separate methods (you could argue its overkill). One where I create an Opp Record with Approval Status = 'New Accounts Final Approval' and another without or test another status.

Comment: THEOPP has already been inserted previously in the test.  It would need an update after that line, as opposed to an insert.

Comment: good shout @sfdc_nijnja - I didn't spot that.